# Pricing elasticity*coefficient from glm

Tags: elasticity, demand, pricing

**Problem:**

I would like to understand the pricing elasticity in an industry while factoring in other independent variables that affect units sold.

**Where I am currently at:**

Much of the data for this industry are fairly public. I have units sold for each company and an industry-standard quality metric for each company. What I don't have are details of competitors' sales and marketing budget/efforts. I have a linear model based on price and the quality metric that significantly predicts about 50% of the variance in the units sold (see below).

```
Residual standard error: 1124 on 246 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5013,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4973 
F-statistic: 123.7 on 2 and 246 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I would now like to use the coefficient of the price of the product and multiply this by the pricing elasticity of demand formula to get a better idea of pricing options. The obvious issue here is that the existing model does not fully predict the dependent variable so I would like to know if it is possible to still use this but quantify the size of the pinch of salt I need for the pricing elasticity of demand slope? Is it simple enough to say that it might be out by a factor of 50% given that's the R^2 of the whole model?

Comment: So basically you are asking for something like a confidence interval for the elasticity?

Comment: Yes, exactly - some way of understanding how reliable the measure is.

Comment: Have you considered any typoe of 'cross-validation', or just cutting off part of the training sample and using it to estimate variance?

Comment: I have pretty much population data.

Comment: Ahh - sorry, I might have misunderstood you. So, I have population data, I am not using sampling to build my model. The issue I have is that the model I built does to completely explain the dependent variable, thus there is an element of supply that is not explained by the 2 variables included in the model (price and quality).